# Call two jobs from latexmk automatically

Tags: latexmk

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111010/406686) to a question about compiling two versions of a document from a latex source from stackoverflow the following command is used to get the problem solved:

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=myfile -pretex="\newcommand{\version}{noanswer}" -usepretex myfile.tex | latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=myfile_solution -pretex="\newcommand{\version}{}" -usepretex myfile.tex "
```

`latexmk` is called twice and it is simple to put this into a wrapper script. However I am curious if it is also possible configure a `.latexmkrc` file in such a way that it automatically does both jobs when you call `latexmk file.tex`. Is it also possible that both jobs are executed in parallel (to use multiple cores of your cpu)?

So, how can I configure a `.latexmkrc` file to get this done? That is may be possible is indicated [here](https://www.ntg.nl/maps/45/06.pdf) (p. 105, Aftermath).

Answer (score 2):

I know of no way doing this purely within `latexmk`, certainly nothing that is at all easy and simple. I suspect that the comment about `latexmk` in the referred-to https://www.ntg.nl/maps/45/06.pdf was made without investigating in detail how to get `latexmk` to do the task of generating multiple output files from one source file.

1. A wrapper script is indeed the most obvious way of doing what is needed.  However I see that the given command line uses `latexmk`'s `-pdflatex=...` option to provide options to `pdflatex`.  Since all the options are supported by `latexmk`, so it's simpler (and I think better) to use

   ```
    latexmk -pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -jobname=myfile -pretex="\newcommand{\version}{noanswer}" -usepretex myfile.tex
    latexmk -pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -jobname=myfile_solution -pretex="\newcommand{\version}{}" -usepretex myfile.tex
   ```
2. Another method that I've used is to have a driver .tex file that simply sets the relevant variable (in this case `\version`) and then inputs the main file.  I've found that quite convenient.  It avoids duplicated TeX code, while having the two .tex files makes it more transparent as to how the solution version is made.  It also avoids having to use a special command line for `latexmk` or `pdflatex`.

In this case, `myfile_solution.tex` could be

```
    \newcommand{\version}{}
    \input{myfile}
```

I would also equip `myfile.tex` with something that would give proper behavior if `\version` isn't defined.  E.g., the first line could be

```
  \providecommand{\version}{noanswer}
```

which only defines `\version` if it is not already defined.

Answer (score 0):

I use a latexmkrc to automatically produce 2 versions from the same tex source. In my case, I am using the exam package. One version is the answer key, and the other version is the exam, quiz or test.

In my tex source, I have a line which selects the version of the document to compile. The \noprintanswers command is provided by the exam package.

```
\ifdefined\answersflag\noprintanswers\else\printanswers \fi
```

This is the relevant part of my .latexmkrc that lives in the same folder as my tex source.

```
my $filename = $ARGV[-1];
($base_name, $path, $ext) = fileparseB( $filename );
if  ($ext ne '.tex' ) {
   $file = "$base_name$ext";
}
else {
   $file = $base_name;
}

$tmp = 'blanks.tmp';
if (-e $tmp) {
   system( "rm $tmp" );
} else {
   system( "touch $tmp" );
   system( "latexmk -jobname=${file}blank -usepretex=\"\\def\\answersflag{}\" ${file} > ${file}blank.log &" );
}
```

The jobs are executed in parallel. It's working for me, and you may be able to adapt it to your case.